# C++- Converting very large integers expressed as strings("2134628961988274893") to binary code

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to directly convert an integer expressed as a string ("18446744073709551616"), that is to large to be expressed as an unsigned long long int, to binary code(0b10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
if you have another way to store obscenely large values please let me know.

Comment: What is your question? There are many ways of storing integers, including base-256 instead of base-10.

Comment: What about using GNU MP Bignum (https://gmplib.org) or ttmath (http://www.ttmath.org)?

Comment: If you want to store / operator on arbitrary precision integers, look into the boost multiprecision library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints.html

Comment: As suggested, there are libraries that can help you work with arbitrary precision floating points or arbitrarily big numbers (like GMP), but if you want to know how those libraries work, take a look at the Numerical Recipes book, last chapter (less-numerical algorithms).

Comment: i am looking for a way to store these large integers as binary code inside of a vector<bool>

Comment: @R-McHale: `std::vector<bool>` is a bad idea that strangely enough got into the standard. Why are you aiming at that?

Comment: That [code](http://ideone.com/fHLbQ1) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ has no native support for arbitrary precision integers, however it's not difficult to implement what is needed for this specific use case. You need to:

1. Chose a format. For example using an `std::vector<unsigned char>` to store numbers in base 256
2. Implement addition of two arbitrary precision numbers in base 256
3. Implement multiplication by 10

Then the program becomes:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> res;
res.push_back(0);
for (int i=0,n=str.size(); i<n; i++) {
    mul10(res);
    add(res, str[i]-'0');
}
```

For example `add` can be implemented with:

```
void add(std::vector<unsigned char>& num, int digit) {
    for (int i=0,n=num.size(); digit && i < n; i++) {
        int x = num[i] + digit;
        num[i] = x & 255;
        digit = x >> 8;
    }
    if (digit) {
        num.push_back(digit);
    }
}
```

Multiplication by 10 is done by multiplying the least significant digit, storing low 8 bits back in the number and keeping the carry `x >> 8` to add it to higher digits. Then you multiply the higher digit, add the carry, store low 8 bits and move the new carry up to higher digits...

Comment: this is in short terms what i already have, i don't like to robustness of the memory required to store data in this way, i was hoping for storing the data in something along the lines of a vector<bool>

Comment: Better use some existing bignum library like [GMLlib](http://gmplib.org/)

Comment: This will be as efficient as a `vector<bool>` because it stores 8 bits in each byte. Actually for a real world implementation it would be better to use say `1<<32` as base to have fewer digits still being able to use the hardware to do the math.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: taking in a gajillion of lines of code with a questionable license, fighting with a build system and prerequisites and compiler/cmake/autoconf/whatever versions instead of implementing a three-lines multiplication by 10? Are you serious?

Comment: I am serious. Efficient bignum algorithms are difficult. Once the OP deals with numbers expressible in many thousands of decimal digits, performance may matter a lot.

Comment: If the question is a learning exercise, then this answer is right on. If there's a need to do something other than read in the number, a library as suggested by @BasileStarynkevitch would be better. And for the record there's no space efficiency difference between `vector<unsigned char>` and `vector<bool>`, but I'd expect `<unsigned char>` to be faster.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: you mean multiplying two large integers with karatsuba may be? Here what is needed is bignum plus single-digit and bignum*10. These two operations are trivial.

Comment: It depends on what they are planning to do with the binary code. An example where no further large number arithmetic operations would be performed is seeding a random number generator from the binary code, allowing the user to enter decimal seed values larger than the usually supported range.